# Tensor appearing as "None" in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm getting an issue when I try to run the below function in a session. It should perform the summation on the func_seq and in each generation it minimizes elsewhere in the code using Tensorflows built in minimize function.

Is there any reason why each generation is showing as "None"? I tried printing just after the sum in the eval function but no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
def eval(func_seq):
    sum = tf.reduce_sum(func_seq)
    sum_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(sum, dtype=tf.float32)
    return sum_tensor
```

This is what I get when I have executed my code:

```
Input:  [  1.46641091e-01   1.49433703e+05   3.90815163e+01   1.88019681e+00
   1.38264828e+05   1.40512295e+01   2.62794423e+00   4.28223938e-01
   3.13967906e+05]
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
Execution time: 0.12505006790161133 seconds
```

Comment: Did you run the compute graph?

Comment: No, I'm not sure what that is actually. Should that be run in my session with my minimize function?

Comment: You'd either have to do `session.run()` or `return sum_tensor.eval()`, but I'm no tensor flow expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to run the minimize function "train" (which was declared elsewhere) in the session and to help visualize each generation in the program I called the method in a print statement.

```
# Declared outside of session
train = optimizer.minimize(eval(func_seq))

...

# Declared in session
sess.run(train)
print("Generation", x, ": ", sess.run(eval(func_seq)))
```